# How can I use electric motor data with my prop data to obtain a power available versus velocity curve?

Tags: aircraft-performance, propeller, engine

I'm not entirely sure this is appropriate for this forum but it's worth a shot...

I have propeller data ($C_T$ , $C_P$ , J , and $\eta$) and very very limited electric brushless motor data (motor diameter, shaft diameter, Kv, voltage range, max amperage) I am trying to put together a power available curve (P vs V) but I'm not exactly sure how to use the data I have to do so.  How do I get shaft power from my engine data?  Or what can I use?

Comment: So your question is about the shaft power vs the voltage? I mean the propeller data have nothing to do here, correct? If so, [here is some information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_constants), but I'm not sure this is complete.

Comment: No.  Power available to the aircraft verses velocity.

Comment: For electric motors, torque is a function of amperage and rotational speed is a function of voltage.

Answer (score 1):

A simple mathematical model for electric motors has very clearly been discussed [here](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/qprop/motor1_theory.pdf)
All you need is Kv, no-load current and Voltage to calculate the shaft power, efficiencies, etc.